# How do I send String data after collecting it from sqlite to another activity

Tags: android

I have sqlite database I succeeded to get all data from it and I stored it in String data and then displayed it using another java class which just has Toast.

Now I am trying to send this data to another activity.

this is the data that I receive from the data base by click on button which has this method

```
    public void viewDetails(View view){

String data= mDbHelper.getALLData();
Message.message(this,data);

}
```

also I display data by using `Toast` from another `class` is called Message , and `viewDetails` methods takes data from `getALLData` mehotd in the

`NotesDbAdapter.java:`

```
  public String getALLData(){
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={KEY_ROWID ,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BODY};
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int cid=cursor.getInt(0);
    String title=cursor.getString(1);   
    String body=cursor.getString(2);
    buffer.append(cid+" "+title+" "+body+"\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
```

I tried to use  intent but it did not work

this is NotesDbAdapter.java:

```js
public class NotesDbAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null, date text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the note
     * @param body the body of the note
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createNote(String title, String body, String date) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_DATE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to update
     * @param title value to set note title to
     * @param body value to set note body to
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body,String date) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

        //This lines is added for personal reason
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);

        //One more parameter is added for data
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
    public String getALLData(){
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={KEY_ROWID ,KEY_TITLE,KEY_BODY};
        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int cid=cursor.getInt(0);
        String title=cursor.getString(1);   
        String body=cursor.getString(2);
        buffer.append(cid+" "+title+" "+body+"\n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }}
```

this The NoteEdit activity where I store data, also this activity has the button that perfomrs collecting data and dispalying it

```js
The NoteEdit activity where I store data:
```

this is Message that has the Toast

```js
public class Message {
 public static void message(Context context,String message){
  
  Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

}
```

what exactly I want to do is to send this data  after colecting it in viewDetails method and sotring it in String data to another activity so I can perform other things on it instead of just display it with Toast

i hope you understand my quotations now

Comment: Please clarify, and also fix formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `Intent` to pass your `data` to say, `DestinationActivity`

```
void viewDetails(View view){
    String data = mDbHelper.getALLData();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now, in your `DestinationActivity`, retrieve your `data` as

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public class Message {
 public static void message(Context context,String message){
  
  Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

}
```

```js
public class Message {
 public static void message(Context context,String message){
  
  Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

}
```